# JavaScript reads XML totally wrong

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm developing a HTML5/Canvas game engine and I'm stuck. The engine draws the map via tilesets, and reads the map data from an XML document, which looks like this:

```
<map>
    <layer id="-1">
        <row>0,0,0</row>
        <row>1,1,1</row>
        <row>0,0,0</row>
    </layer>

    <layer id="1">
        <row>0,0,0</row>
        <row>1,1,1</row>
        <row>0,0,0</row>
    </layer>
</map>
```

And the JavaScript which loads the data in a 2-dimensional array:

```
var layers = xml.getElementsByTagName("layer");
for(var i in layers)
{
    var rows = layers[i].childNodes;
    for(var j in rows)
    {
        array[i][j] = rows[j].nodeValue;
    }   
}
```

The problem: the returned data is just a mishmash of "null", "", and "undefined". Also, the array seems to be smaller then necessary, because before I go through all the  values I check the number of nodes (with the length attribute), and it's always more then the actual number of nodes.

Comment: Please show the line where you initialized the array too :)

Comment: In JavaScript, a `for-in` loop is used for iterating over object properties, NOT array elements.  Use incremental loops `for (var i=0; i<layers.length; i++)` (but use store `layers.length` in a variable since it's a live nodelist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `textContent` instead of `nodeValue`. The former returns the correct value such as `"0,0,0"`.
2. Since text nodes are also child nodes, you should skip them (check the node's `nodeType`). These are filling your array with holes, and making them larger than needed. The text nodes are basically the whitespace of the indenting. Solving this will require an additional counter.
3. Use a normal `for` loop, not a `for in` loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/DhKJr/

Comment: Thank you for the fast replying, the code works like a charm. I read up on text nodes earlier and tried to solve the problem, unfortunately it did not work at all.

Comment: Also I only used for in loops because I tought it was the equivalent of foreach (yes, I'm pretty much a newcomer in Javascript).